# Generating subsets from set, that are in order and follow custom rule

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine I have a set A={A1, A2, A3, A4, A5}.

Combinations of subsets that contain 2 elements would be:

```
{
  {A1, A2},
  {A1, A3}, 
  {A1, A4},
  {A1, A5},
  {A2, A3},
  {A2, A4},
  {A2, A5},
  {A3, A4},
  {A3, A5},
  {A4, A5},
}
```

### Rules for creating the subsets should be:

- Subsets need to be in specific order
- Subset containing element X, needs to be as far as possible from the next subset that would contain that element X
- All possible combinations should be used while generating the order
- This should work for any set size and with any subset size

Subsets created by the rules above, in order:

```
{ 
  1:  {A1, A2}, // A1 is used here
  2:  {A3, A4}, 
  3:  {A5, A1}, // A1 is used again, as far as possible. By now all elements are used in subsets
  4:  {A2, A4}, // This combination is used because A5 from subset 5 will be very close to A5 from subset 3.
  5:  {A3, A5},
  6:  {A1, A4}, // A1 is used again, as far as possible
  7:  {A2, A5},
  8:  {A1, A3}, // A1 is used again, as far as possible
  9:  {A4, A5},
  10: {A2, A3}
}
```

I need this so I can create algorithm in code.
So far i couldn't find any matching pattern, so i can say for given X generate me or give me the subset Y.

Comment: I think you need to specify what exactly you mean by "as far as possible". Do you want the minimum distance between any two equal elements to be the biggest possible?

Comment: yes, thats what i think

Comment: Please be my savior!